# How to align Grouping Text of only two panels out of many Panels in a page center?

Tags: css, asp.net, panel, legend, fieldset

In my page there are many panels and grouping texts. For two panels the grouping text has to be aligned center. I have tried:

```
legend {
margin:0 auto;
```

}

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel13" runat="server" GroupingText="<b>Grouping Text</b>">
  <table>
     <tr></tr>
  </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

But it will make grouping text of all the panels center. I need to align the grouping text center only to two panels. Kindly help me.

Comment: use `text-align:center` maybe? Just guessing, hard to say without your full code. Create a fiddle perhaps?

Comment: @indira how about adding a custom style name to the element where you want to grouptext center and apply class as follows: `.customcss legend {margin:0 auto}`

Comment: @GurtejSingh Code is updated

Answer (score 1):

Give specific class to the panel for which you want the text to be aligned centre. Check the example below.

```css
legend.align-centre {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

legend {
font-size: 16px;
padding: 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>
  <legend class="align-centre">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type speci</legend>
  
  <legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type speci</legend>
  
  <legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type speci</legend>
  
  <legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type speci</legend>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.